# Postsharp logging to a text file in C#

Tags: c#, logging, postsharp

I am fairly new to using PostSharp. I have been able to get it to output trace messages to a the System.Console backend, but can anyone give me a basic sample as to how output the trace messages to a simple text file please?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is,

- implement some kind of logging service (or just use an existing library, for example log4net)
- create an aspect which will then use that log service to write your stuff to the log file

**Update**:

There is an extension for PostSharp using Log4Net, see

http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/postsharp-toolkits-update-support-for-log4net-and-system-diagnostics-trace

Just google for log4net and PostSharp, it will point you in the right direction.

http://www.lobsterfs.co.uk/blog/postsharp-and-log4net/

Comment: I get the following error:

cannot convert source type PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics.LogLevel to target type string

My program.cs file looks like so:

[Log(LogLevel.Info, "Log Something Text")]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(HelloWorld());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        [Log]
        static string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hi";
        }

I have added the changes required in the appconfig file and the assemblyinfo file.

Comment: Excuse the poor formatting, but is it possible for you to create a quick example for me? I really am struggling with this.

Comment: Here is a complete tutorial how to use logging and PostSharp:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28407/Log-PostSharp-AOP-and-logging

Comment: How would I go about importing this example? The tutorial is for VS2008. The current version is for 2012 though.

Comment: All newer VisualStudios are able to convert old solutions. It is done automatically once you open the solution.